# Responsive Images Using Bootstrap not coming with any solution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't get the code to show images responsively. The image is not coming in smaller screens at all. and also you can see in the image that social icons become vertical below the navbar brand. is there any way to make it on the top left when the screen size is small. please help and any would be appreciated. and please let me know what wrong approach I am taking

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/5.1.1/bootstrap-social.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
            <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
        </button>

        <a class="mr-auto navbar-brand nh myfont" href=".\index.html"> <img src="images/logo.png" width="60px" height="70px"> Sidhant Aggarwal</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nl">
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href=".\contactus.html"> Certifications</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class = "fa fa-linkedin fa-xs"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-github fa-xs"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<img class="img-fluid" src="images/first.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: small screen[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-row` class in your icons block

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/5.1.1/bootstrap-social.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
            <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
        </button>

        <a class="mr-auto navbar-brand nh myfont" href=".\index.html"> <img src="images/logo.png" width="60px" height="70px"> Sidhant Aggarwal</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nl">
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href=".\contactus.html"> Certifications</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class = "fa fa-linkedin fa-xs"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-github fa-xs"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<img class="img-fluid" src="images/first.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still not working? why did you ask to add this? whatever the rationale behind it, nothing changed

Comment: brother watch snippet, your icons are now horizontal in small screens

Comment: @outofBounds If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!